# Spring task:scheduled-tasks bugged?

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have discovered the following issue and I would like to know if it is normal behavior (and if so why?) or if it is a bug of Spring. I have a spring context file that define a Scheduled-tasks. If this file is imported multiple times in my whole application context then the task is executed multiple time as well.

E.g.
I have a context file: a-context.xml:

```
...
<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="5"/>

<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="scheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="archiveTask" method="run" cron="0 * * * * *"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<bean id="archiveTask" class="ch.post.ehealth.referral.core.task.ArchiveTask" />
...
```

Let say I also have this b-context.xml:

```
...
<import resource="classpath:./a-context.xml" />
...
```

Finally my application-context.xml:

```
...
<import resource="classpath:./a-context.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:./b-context.xml" />
...
```

In this case my task is executed twice because it is "imported" twice. If I move the task:scheduled-tasks part in application-context.xml then it is only executed one time as expected. Is that normal and if yes why?
I don't understand because behavior is different with beans. E.g. that kind of situation doesn't make problem with beans that will only be created once.

Thanks

**Update**
My web.xml:

```
...
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-   class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.gwtrpcspring.RemoteServiceDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>
...
```

Comment: If it is executed twice your context is loaded twice. You are probably loading the `a-contxt.xml` in both the `ContextLoaderListener`  and `DispatcherServlet` both are creating their own `ApplicationContext` and hence each schedule the execution. And that behavior isn't different with beans you will end up with multiple instances.

Comment: Nop this is not the case. I don't load any context with DispatcherServlet only application-context. As said moving the definition of scheduled-task from a-context to application-context solve the issue

Comment: You are aware that the `DispatcherServlet` by default loads a xml file called `[servlet-name]-servlet.xml`. It will only be the case if the xml file is loaded twice for whatever reason in all other cases it will not happen as the beans override one another.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that and I have no [servlet-name]-servlet.xml as said only application-context

Comment: Without seeing how things are loaded it is impossible to say. As mentioned the imports don't matter as they are overriding each other. It will only be the case if the files are loaded twice.

Answer (score 0):

In the below code, 'application-context.xml' is loaded. and in appication-context.xml you have imported a.context twice. It means it has been loaded twice so our scehduler also will be triggered twice. Still spring do not able to avoid if a bean xml is already loaded then avoid loading it second time. So we have to be careful when importing especially when we use scheduler.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```